# No sound (speakers or jack) on ASUS ZenBook on Ubuntu 18

Tags: 18.04, sound, asus

I have bought a new ASUS ZenBook, installed Ubuntu (I'm new to it) and wipping out windows completely, and things work well apart from the sound.

WHAT HAPPENS
Basically I cannot get any sound out of the in-built speakers (harman / kardon), neither can I use the jack audio output.
Interestingly, if I connect in bluetooth to my home speakers it works well (is it a sound card in the speakers themselves?).

- DETAILS I have tried a number of steps from what I read online:

  - ubuntu settings/sound
    --> speakers not mutted
    --> no mention of "dummy output" -> instead the device for sound output is "Speakers - Built-in Audio"
  - killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse* FOLLOWED BY pulseaudio -k
  - sudo alsa force-reload
  - reboot
  - alsamixer and check the master and speaker are not mutted
  - sudo gedit /etc/default/speech-dispatcher and try both run=yes and run=no (no difference after rebooting, so I switched back to the
    default which is no)

Here is the details about my configuration:
http://alsa-project.org/db/?f=b74bdb035c8a8582850374e6481ea6edc2f68f42

How should I approach the problem? I do not know where to start, or why this is so difficult.

Thanks for your help!
Romain

Comment: I have an ASUS ZenBook, model UX533F. I confirm the sound is not working out-of-the box with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, but it's working alright with Ubuntu 19.04 (Linux kernel 5.0.0.x).

Answer (score 1):

The sound now works!

Updating to Ubuntu 18.10 didn't work. But worked is one or both of the two concurrent steps I took:

- disable secure boot
- upgrade to Ubuntu 19.04 (thank you Bludzee!)

Bad news though: my computer now struggles to boot (actually it intermittently manages to boot by itself one time out of 6, it's pretty bad!)

Comment: I had the same problem with this laptop model mostly failing to boot. I fixed it by installing the latest BIOS and firmware from the [Asus website](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-14-UX433FA/HelpDesk_BIOS).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which zenbook you use,

but I have this problem with my zenbook ux533 (ubuntu 18.04) before.

The solution for me is update the kernel to 4.20

I use ukuu to upgrade the kernel, detail I wrote in the readme (issue 1)

https://github.com/ShangChunLin/zenbook-issuse-with-ubuntu18.04

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, read this post and thought 'aah, cant be asked right now..' 
Used my laptop 2 days without sound and suddenly it was fixed. Automatic updating and some restarts seemed to be all it needed.
(ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS)

laziness gets rewarded sometimes!